# BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named X is expected to be of type X but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I have such classes and Spring context.

How to fix this wrong Java configuration, not xml?

I'd tried some solutions from other posts, but without success.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class XCalculationService implements VoidService<X> {
}

public interface VoidService<Input> {
}

@AllArgsConstructor
public class XService {
private XCalculationService calculationService;
}

@Configuration
public class ServiceConfiguration {
@Bean
public OrderService orderService(XCalculationService calculationService) {
    return new XService(calculationService);
}

@Bean
public XCalculationService calculationService() {
    return new XCalculationService ();
}
}
```

Error

```
BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'calculationService' is expected to be of type 'com.x.XCalculationService' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is 100% fix:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

Comment: Makes it "Cannot subclass final class X"  - kotlin woes

Comment: Know why you have this problem, why this fixes it, and what that means: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html

Answer (score 2):

Java proxies are working on interfaces, not concrete classes.
Reasoning with spring documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html

`If the target object to be proxied implements at least one interface then a JDK dynamic proxy will be used.`

Therefore, when using aspect/proxy based annotations as `@Transactional`, Spring will attempt to proxify the concrete class and resulting object will be instance of `VoidService` interface not `XCalculationService`.

Therefore you can solve it two ways:

1. use @Arthur solution and turn off Java's interface proxy in favor of CGLib for transaction support
   `@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)`
2. Instead of using `XCalculationService` type in injectable fields, use only its proxied interface aka `VoidService`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have got `@ComponentScan` somewhere activated and it scans your `@Service` annotated `XCalculationService` class.

So you should **either remove** `@Service` from `XCalculationService`

or **remove**

```
@Bean
public XCalculationService calculationService() {
    return new XCalculationService ();
}
```

from `ServiceConfiguration`

Comment: Removed @Service, same error. I have only for web 
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.x.web"})